# python pytz, DST not included in conversion

Tags: python, pytz

I'm converting a naive datetime object to another timezone. But it doesn't include the DST (Daylight Saving Time). This is what i do:

```
#my datetime object
datetime_from #contains: 05, 07, 2012, 10 00 --- (05-07-2012 10:00)

#Add timezone
ams = datetime_from.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam'))

print(ams.hour) #prints 10

#convert to GMT
gmt = datetime.astimezone(ams, pytz.timezone("GMT"))

print(gmt.hour) #prints 9
```

The problem is, is that gmt.hour should print 8 instead of 9 because of DST.

Is there an easy way to include DST in this conversion?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam').localize(datetime(2012, 7, 5, 10, 0)).astimezone(pytz.timezone('GMT'))
datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 5, 8, 0, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'GMT'>)
```